# How to instruct java gradle plugin to not use the root project name to construct the module jar?

Tags: java, gradle

As part of my CI process a symlink directory is made with an arbitrary name like "module" that will always point to the correct build directory. Unfortunately the java plugin seems to use this when it decides to name the resulting JAR file `module.jar`.

How do I tell gradle to use some other properties in order to determine the jar name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options to achieve this, here are some of them:

- set the `rootProject.name` in `settings.gradle` to make it independent of the directory name (always a good idea)
- set the [`archivesBaseName`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:archivesBaseName) on the project to influence the base name of all archive tasks
- set the [`baseName`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:baseName) on the `jar` task to whatever you like
- set the [`archiveName`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName) on the `jar` task to whatever you like

Comment: Since my archive base name is derived, I put it in my corresponding build.gradle files. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the `archivesBaseName` is derived from the root project name which is derived from the directory name if not explicitly set in `settings.gradle`. So setting the root project name to a fixed value would also fix it, just as I described. In my opinion also the preferable way, but whatever suits you best. :-)

Comment: I actually can't do that in my case since life cycle-wise it's not determined yet when I'm in settings due to my architecture. :(

Comment: What is not determined? *confused*

Comment: Me too, I'm having a hard time understanding the variable scoping in gradle configs. I have two gradle files, my build.gradle and a custom.gradle that defines some custom tasks I want to take place during CI.

My custom tasks actually need a variable defined in the local scope of the `build.gradle` file. I'm unsure of how to ensure that variable is set when invoking tasks inside of `custom.gradle`. It seems that the configuration step does not capture what's present in `build.gradle`.

Comment: I'd need to see your files to explain what is going on, but basically local variables (defined with `def`) are local to the script (or block) where they are defined. If you need something in multiple scripts, set it in some `ext` scope, like `project.ext.foo = 'bar'` or `task.ext.foo = 'bar'`. Once set like this you can set and get the variable without `ext`, like `project.foo` or `task.foo`.